# Multiple instances of CodeMirror textarea on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, codemirror

I'm trying to make a little project for job interview questions and have a bunch of questions with answers and code examples on the page. Each is inside a .collapsible div from Materialize.css, and when clicked shows the answer and code example.

What is the best way to go about this? I tried putting initializer into a function, grabbing all my textareas form the DOM, looping through them and turning them into CodeMirror textareas.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName('code-block');

  function createEditorFrom(selector) {
    let editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(selector, {
      lineNumbers : false,
      mode: "swift",
    });
  }

  for (var x = 0; x < blocks.length; x++) {
    createEditorFrom(blocks[x]);
  }

  // Callback for Collapsible open
  $('.collapsible').collapsible({
    onOpen: function() { 
      // call editor.refresh()?
    },
  });

});
```

This does work but I feel like it is not a very elegant way of solving this issue. Is there a better way to do this?

Questions:

1. Is there a better way to create all the CodeMirror textareas?
2. The code in the editors does not appear until clicked. Nothing I do makes it work. Calling editor.refresh() (with setTimeout), and autorefresh: true.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you will have to do anyhow is keeping a reference to your CodeMirror instances (eg. to get/set their value), so createEditorForm will have to return the CodeMirror instance, & you could for example push them to an array in the loop:

```
function createEditorFrom(selector) {
  return CodeMirror.fromTextArea(selector, {
    lineNumbers : false,
    mode: "swift",
  });
}

let codeblocks = [];
for (var x = 0; x < blocks.length; x++) {
  codeblocks.push({
     CM: createEditorFrom(blocks[x]), 
     el: blocks[x]
  });
}
```

I've encountered a similar problem to *"The code in the editors does not appear until clicked"* and I even wrote a comment next to the solution. Translated to your implementation that would be:

```
function createEditorFrom(selector) {
  var instance = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(selector, {
    lineNumbers : false,
    mode: "swift",
  });
  // make sure the CodeMirror unit expands by setting a null character
  instance.setValue('\0');
  instance.setValue('');
  return instance;
}
```

For what it's worth, I also used some CSS tweaks to ensure consistent initial & max-height rendering:

```
/* CodeMirror */
.CodeMirror { height: auto; overflow: auto; max-height: 250px; }
.CodeMirror-scroll { height: auto; min-height: 24px; }
```

*Is there a better way to create all the CodeMirror textareas [than by looping through them]?*

Yes, you can *lazy initialize* them if they are not visible on page load (and actually I believe it's better to initialize them only when the parent node of the `<textarea>` is visible, I'm not sure if CodeMirror requires render-info (like [Element.getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)), e.g. only load them `onOpen` of their collapsible parent.

Comment: A few things. 1) I don't need a reference to any of the textareas because they are dynamically rendered in my Rails app. 2) Your answer regarding having to click the textarea to show the code did not help in my situation but I appreciate the help. 3) I didn't really think of initializing them when the collapsible is opened so that's what route I took so thanks for that.

Comment: @TaylorA.Leach ah 2) was worth a try. For 1), you'll need a ref for when the data needs to be saved after editing with `CodeMirrorinstance.getValue()`, or am I missing something

Comment: I'm not using the getValue() in my situation. The content is dynamically generated in rails inside the actual textarea.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up initializing each one when the collapsible is opened. This works but I guess it would need to be adjusted if there were multiple CodeMirror textareas in the same collapsible.

I also added in a check becuase otherwise when the collapsible gets opened, then closed, then reopened it would create a duplicate textarea.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.collapsible').collapsible({
    onOpen: createCodeBlock
  });

  function createCodeBlock(target) {
    var card     = target.context.parentElement.parentElement;
    var textarea = card.getElementsByClassName('code-block')[0];

    // Placeholder class that prevents the duplicate creation of
    // the same textarea when the collapsible is closed then reopened.
    if (!textarea.classList.contains("created")) {
      CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textarea, {
        lineNumbers: false,
        mode: "swift",
      });
      textarea.className += "created";
    }
  }

});
```